# how do i store the value of the 3rd line from the file in java and extract specific column details

Tags: java, regex, matlab

I have a file wherein after reading the file i need to extract the 3rd line from the file into a variable or  a structure in java and thereby extract specific column details into different array variables.

```
   BufferedReader br = null;
        String strLine = "";
        try {
            LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
             while (((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) && reader.getLineNumber() <= 3){
                System.out.println(strLine);
            }
           reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
        }
```

Here i cant seem to find a way to just read the 3rd line ,any idea how to do that and more over precisely after reading the 3rd line i will need to extract information into an array list and store them separately....

The file has the data in the below format:
DATA ATTACHED
TYPE NO :HELLO-421                  PROCESS  :ABCD                    ID:1234
BATCH ID  :ABC123.5                  DATE     :09/25/2018             CATEGORY:Hello-CE

I am able to print the output as below in the console
DATA ATTACHED
TYPE NO :HELLO-421                  PROCESS  :ABCD                    ID:1234
BATCH ID  :ABC123.5                  DATE     :09/25/2018             CATEGORY:Hello-CE

So the challenge here is how do i store the results in an input array and read/extract only line 3 details from the resultset.

The equivalent code in matlab version has something like this:

```
hdr=textread(filename,'%s',3,'whitespace','\n');
resultset=regexp(hdr{3},'^BATCH ID  :(?<batch>[A-Z\-\.0-9]+)\s+DATE     :(?<tdate>[0-9/]+)\s+CATEGORY :(?<category>[A-Za-z\-0-9]+$)','names');
```

and then once regexp is done ,the extract is done using resultset.batch;
resultset.date;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can just make an `ArrayList<String>` and instead of printing the `strLine` Variable, you can add it to the list.

and then you can get the line you need by getting the third element in the List:

```
String thirdLine = listName.get(2);
```

Comment: Thanks,but i was able tor read the 3rd line in the code using the below script:
  int n = 2; // The line number
      String line;
      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              br.readLine();
          line = br.readLine();
          System.out.println(line);
Now,i need to parse and extract only specific fields from the resulting output in separate string ?
BATCH ID :ABC123.1     DATE :09/21/2018      PRODUCT :Hello-CA
I tried using substring start with colon and end with whitespace ,it wont work?

Comment: not sure if thats what you are looking for but:

`String thirdLine = "BATCH ID :ABC123.1 DATE :09/21/2018 PRODUCT :Hello-CA";
thirdLine = thirdLine.replaceAll(":", "");
String[] words = thirdLine.split(" ");`
  
  
the value of words is { "BATCH", "ID", "ABC123.1", "DATE", "09/21/2018", "PRODUCT", "Hello-CA" }